# OpenSSL version 1.0.1e in CentOS 6 -- Heartbleed Vulnerability

Tags: openssl, heartbleed, centos

I was reading the Heartbleed vulnerability in the OpenSSL and in its [official website](http://heartbleed.com/), they have a list which mentioned that `version 1.0.1 to 1.0.1f` are affected, as shown in below pic.

[image]

I have CentOS 6 installed in my server and updated as per latest available versions in `yum` repository.

redhat release -
`[root@SERVER ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)`

uname output -
`[root@SERVER ~]# uname -a
Linux SERVER 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 22 06:48:29 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Now, when i am checking for OpenSSL version, it shows me the below information -
`[root@SERVER ~]# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013`

So, in version output, i am able to see that version is 1.0.1e which is affected with `Heartbleed Vulnerability` and it also shows me that version was last updated on `11 Feb 2013`.

I have following doubts --

1. Does this means all the CentOS 6 machines are affected with **Heartbleed** ?
2. RedHat is not providing patches for CentOS ?
3. What should i do now ? Manually install the latest OpenSSL package OR migrate to CentOS 7 (although i am not sure whether CentOS 7 contains updated packages or not) ?

Comment: plz update your server kernel also :P

Comment: Already there in `uname -a` output

Comment: sorry , i mean to say update it with latest kernel if possible

Comment: as per `yum`, everything (including packages and kernel) all are updated up to latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most distributors don't just upgrade to the latest version of OpenSSL since this could have unintended side effects (slightly different behavior or even new bugs). Instead they just backport the patch and keep the version number. This means you should not only look at the openssl version but at the distributors version number to.

For CentOS 6.8 this is currently OpenSSL 1.0.1e but [vendor release 48.el6_8.3](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/updates/6.8/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-48.el6_8.3.x86_64.html). This release includes all recent bugfixes and also the fix for Heartbleed:

```
* Mon Apr 07 2014 TomÃ¡Å¡ MrÃ¡z <tmraz@redhat.com> 1.0.1e-23
  - fix CVE-2014-0160 - information disclosure in TLS heartbeat extension
```

Comment: Interesting thing. `Instead they just backport the patch` -- Is this means that redhat copy and paste the code from OpenSSL or write its own code for every vulnerability ?

Comment: @GauravKansal: This depends. If the original code in question is about the same in the old and the new version then one could often simply apply the diff as patch, maybe slightly modified. In other cases one need to write new code which fixes the problem in the old version in a different way.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. This must be a tough task to simply understand the old code, write a new one for each and every vulnerability AND do this for every package (like OpenSSL, BIND and many more).

Comment: @GauravKansal: yes, it is time consuming. But the alternative would be to customers force to always use the latest greatest and most untested code :(